# How do I connect PyCharm to a remote docker registry?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, docker-registry

I have pycharm installed on one server and have docker installed on another server.

I wish to connect PyCHarm to docker on the other server.

I have added the IP address and username and password of the server but the test connection fails.

What exactly do I enter into this configuration screen in PyCharm?
Is there a specific format of address I need to use?

[image]

Comment: Have you opened any port on your Docker server that accepts connections?

Answer (score 1):

Is the IP address/ address url needs to be a public one as specified [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/docker-registry-dialog.html)

Also keep in mind - the screen you are trying to put your details into is to add a custom docker registry details and not connect your server to another docker server. If you are trying to add a new custom registry, then great! otherwise you might want to have some ssh tunnelling to connect 2 servers.